# Transferring data between layers of an application

Tags: c#

If I have a C# application with a 5 layer architecture, much like what is presented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx, and I take the strict interaction approach of allowing a layer to only interact with the layer below, I am running into trouble when getting data in my Data layer and passing that data back up to my Business layer.

For example, if I have a business object called MyObject that is defined in my Business layer, but information needed to construct an object of type MyObject is retrieved from the database in the Data layer, my Business layer needs a reference to my Data layer in order to interact with the database.  But, my Data layer then also needs a reference to the Business layer, since that is where the MyObject definition lives and the Data layer needs to construct an object of that type from the database results and give that data back to the Business layer.  Now we have a circular dependency between the Business layer and the Data layer.

I am wondering what the proper approach is to solve this problem.

I have thought about using DTO objects defined in my Data layer to pass information back to the Business layer.  This would work since the Business layer is able to interact with the Data layer, but not vice versa.  It just seems like this might be an awful lot of duplicate code to basically mimic the business object definitions in the Data layer.

I also thought about creating interfaces for all of my business objects and putting those interfaces into a separate project that both the Business layer and Data layer can interact with.  That way, I can pass instances of the interface and the only common reference between the Business layer and Data layer is the project where the interfaces are defined.  I don't see many implementations of this either.

I am wondering what others have done to solve this problem.

Comment: show your code and explain where you are getting error. If possible give your exception details and from which line it is coming

Comment: Well, it isn't exactly a coding problem but rather a design/architecture problem.  I don't have a specific exception as it is more a question about technique on how to solve a circular project dependency problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you would benefit from AutoMapper.
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Each layer of your application should have it's own "version of the truth." The data layer has POCOs that are shaped based on the storage format of the data. Then your interface between data and business layers should take those data POCOs and map them into business POCOs. Rinse and repeat for the business/ui boundary or any other layers you may have.

The shape of the data that describes an object best in one layer shouldn't dictate how another layer can best describe an object. (i.e. The data layer might need foreign key ids, but the view can do just fine with an in-memory reference.)

Comment: I've used AutoMapper in the past on DTOs transferred across the wire, but I have never used it to map between layers.  I like your suggestion, though, and it seems to be the cleanest solution.  My only concern is the data POCOs and business POCOs will be very similar and I may get questions from other team members on the design approach since it requires two objects representing much the same thing with maybe only minor differences for things like foreign key representations.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to construct the data on the Data side, then define the type in the data access layer.  If the object is constructed in the DL, then that's where the type belongs.  This allows you to avoid the circular reference.  Just reference the Data project in the business layer project, and you have access to the type.

Another solution is to return raw results from the data access layer, and construct the object in the Business layer from the raw results.

Comment: This is one of the approaches I was contemplating but it just seemed a little weird to have my business objects defined in the data layer....which is solved by your second suggestion.  The problem I have there is raw results in the business layer would seem to indicate that the business layer has to have references to data assemblies which I am trying to limit to only the data layer.  I am probably trying to be too "pure" about this and will have to settle on something a bit less than "pure".  Thanks for your answer.